# MongoDb Duplicate Entry Error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hi why I'm getting duplicate entry errors. I do check in advance if the document is in the database. My model requires uniqueness for `idName`. I load the data from a JSON array, prooven is only false, there are no entries with true.

```
async.map recipe.zutaten,
  (ingredient, cb) ->
    #Save all ingredients
    ingredient.idName = ingredient.name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/gi, "").toLowerCase()
    ingredientModel.find({ idName: ingredient.idName }, (err, ingredientFound) ->
      return next err if err

      ingredientsJson = {"idName":ingredient.idName, "name":ingredient.name, "amount":ingredient.amount}
      #if found just pass it to recipes
      if ingredientFound? && ingredientFound.length > 0
        ingredientsJson.prooven = true
        return cb null, ingredientsJson
      #if not found evaluate if to save
      else
        #if not prooven just add the json to recipes
        if(ingredient.prooven? && ingredient.prooven == false)
          ingredientsJson.prooven = false
          return cb null, ingredientsJson
        #if prooven save it into database
        else
          ingredientDBObject = new ingredientModel()
          ingredientDBObject.name = ingredient.name
          ingredientDBObject.idName = ingredient.idName
          ingredientDBObject.save((err) ->
            return cb err if err
            ingredientsJson.prooven = true
            return cb null, ingredientsJson
          )
    )
    ...
```

Error

```
{ [MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: database.ingredients.$idName_1  dup key: { : "zitronensaft" }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: database.ingredients.$idName_1  dup key: { : "zitronensaft" }',
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  errmsg: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: database.ingredients.$idName_1  dup key: { : "zitronensaft" }' }
```

Comment: I guess the problem is related to the asynchronous nature of find. Async iterates through ingredients even if the cb is not returned yet. I already moved `ingredient.idName = ingredient.name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/gi, "").toLowerCase()` inside the find function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to `async.map` it does not wait for a callback. The use of async.mapSeries fixed the problem. Map Series waits for the cb to be resolved:
https://github.com/caolan/async#mapSeries

```
...
async.mapSeries recipes,
  (recipe, next) ->  
    ...      
    async.mapSeries recipe.zutaten,
      (ingredient, cb) ->
           ...
```